# Where am I going wrong in this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I'm in the 217th challenge of freecodecamp which is profile lookup.

This is the problem definition

**We have an array of objects representing different people in our contacts lists. 
A lookUpProfile function that takes firstName and a property (prop) as arguments has been pre-written for you.
The function should check if firstName is an actual contact's firstName and the given property (prop) is a property of that contact.
If both are true, then return the "value" of that property.
If firstName does not correspond to any contacts then return "No such contact"
If prop does not correspond to any valid properties then return "No such property"**

I saw many using the equality operator within the "if" loop but I wanted to solve it using the "hasOwnProperty" function. I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
  {
    
if(contacts.hasOwnProperty(firstName) && contacts.hasOwnProperty(prop))
  {
    return contacts.prop;
  }
  return "No such property";
  }
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare actual value of `firstName` property, `(contacts[i].firstName == firstName)`.

See more details in comments.

Here is working [code](https://plnkr.co/edit/LT9X7ToTUoJNJwszw2TL?p=preview)

```js
// Code goes here

var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
   // Only change code below this line
   for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++){
      // use i as array index, to access particular contact object
      if((contacts[i].firstName == firstName) && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
           //dot notation will not work here, use []
           return contacts[i][prop];
      }
      return "No such property";
    }
   // Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
console.log(lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you just forgot to lookup for the object in your array, and not your entire array :

```
for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {

    var contact = contacts[i];

    if(contact.hasOwnProperty('firstName') && contact.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return contact.prop;
    }

    return "No such property";

}
```

Comment: this won't work because the `firstname` being passed in is not a variable

Comment: @MB
 yea, it isn't working. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: anyways, as @oKonyk pointed out, teh if statement for the firstname is wrong. see the edits to my post for correct answer

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not referencing the single contact in the loop `contacts[i]`
2. fix the if statement to compare the first name
3. You have to get the property value from a variable like below

```js
var contacts = [
    {
        "firstName": "Akira",
        "lastName": "Laine",
        "number": "0543236543",
        "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Harry",
        "lastName": "Potter",
        "number": "0994372684",
        "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Sherlock",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "number": "0487345643",
        "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Kristian",
        "lastName": "Vos",
        "number": "unknown",
        "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
    }
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
// Only change code below this line
  for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++)
  {
    
if(contacts[i].firstName == firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
  {
    //return contacts[i].prop;
     alert(contacts[i][prop]);
  }
  //return "No such property";
   alert("No such property");
  }
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes");
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `firstName` in `lookUpProfile` function is not a property. It is a value for firstName property.

when we call `lookUpProfile("Akira", "likes")`, your code tries to check if the property "Akira" exist in the data (which does not) and it does not return the property. You need to replace `contacts.hasOwnProperty(firstName)` in your if statement with `contacts.firstName === firstName`

In addition, you need to get contact in your loop:

```
var contact = contacts[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code will work for one test case but not for all that are required to pass the session.

```
    function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName) {
                return contacts[i][prop];
            }
        }
        else {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
    return "No such contact";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
Here is the solution to this problem 

function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){
    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
        if (contacts[i].firstName == firstName && prop in contacts[i]) {
            return contacts[i][prop];
        } else if (!(firstName in contacts[i]) && i == (contacts.length - 1)) {
            return "No such contact";
        } else if ((typeof contacts[i][prop] == 'undefined')) {
            return "No such property";
        }
    }
```